# How to skip lines when reading a file with numpy.fromfile?

Tags: python, numpy, file-read, fromfile

I am reading a `.pksc` file that contains coordinates and velocities of a large number of astronomical objects. I am doing the reading with

```
import numpy as np
f=open('halos_10x10.pksc') 
data = np.fromfile(f,count=N*10,dtype=np.float32)
```

The file can be found [here](https://mocks.cita.utoronto.ca/data/websky/v0.0/). It is very large and I want to skip the first `m` objects (the first `m` lines corresponding to these objects, if there are lines in the file). How can I do this, I see nowhere an option for skipping? Optionally, it would be also nice to be able to skip the last `k` objects from the file. Tnx!

Comment: Do you have some sample of the data in the PKSC file? I'm trying to search for it, and the only real hits I've gotten are for cryptography.

Comment: `fromfile` is not a line oriented reader. What's the format of this file?  What's 'object'?

Comment: @ZachYoung Thanks, I included a link to where the file can be downloaded. It is from an astrophysics simulation by a research group

Comment: That's a lazy man's answer. Don't expect us to search that directory for documentation, much less down load one of the "very large" files to see for ourselves.

Comment: @hpaulj, it's binary, there's no way to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: With a binary file, the only controls you have are `offset` and `count`.  Or open the file yourself and `seek` forward to the start.  `lines` mean nothing in a binary file.

Comment: OP, I posted a revised answer.

Comment: @hpaulj I couldn't find more information and I was running between tasks, being only able to quickly reply to Zach Young. Assuming malevolence on my side is not in the spirit of SO, but you should know about it with your reputation. And I don't "expect" anything from you, on SO people just help each other - or not, without accusing each other. Anyways, thanks for the bit you shared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to appreciate is that your PKSC file is binary and is one continuous string of bytes with no discernible breaks in the data.

Text files on the other hand have lines that are clearly delimited by some line-break character, so it's pretty easy to read *a **line** at a time* and ignore M lines at the front, then read the remaining number of lines you care about: `REMAINING_LINES = ALL_LINES - M_LINES - K_LINES`.

`np.fromfile()` reads the binary file *an **item** at a time*.

To do this, it needs the `dtype=` param to tell the reader how big an item is.  In the case of a PKSC file, we represent an item as a 32-bit integer, `np.int32`.

I searched and searched but could not find a spec for the file.  Fortunately the link you provided has a sample Python script for reading the file; and I also found a well-documented Python lib for dealing with these kinds of files (**websk.py**, linked below).

I've learned that the PKSC file has the following properties:

- The first 3 items are *header* items:

  - the first header item is a count of the *records* of relevant data that follow the header items
- each relevant data record contains 10 items

`np.fromfile()` also takes the `count=` param as an instruction of exactly how many items to read.

Here's how to read the 3 header items, get the total number of Halo records that follow, and read the first two records (10 items per record):

```py
Nitems_per_record = 10

f = open('halos_10x10.pksc')

headers = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=3)
print(f'Headers: {headers}')
print(f'This file contains {headers[0]} records with Halo data')

record1 = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems_per_record)
print(f'First record:\n{record1}')

record2 = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems_per_record)
print(f'Second record:\n{record2}')
```

```
Headers: [2079516 2079516 2079516]
This file contains 2079516 records with Halo data
First record:
[ 1170060708 -1011158654 -1006515961 -1022926100  1121164875  1110446585  1086444250  1170064687 -1011110709 -1006510502]
Second record:
[ 1170083367 -1013908122 -1006498824 -1014626384 -1020456945 -1033004197  1084104229  1170090354 -1013985376 -1006510502]
```

According to [websky.py](https://github.com/simonsobs/websky_model/blob/master/websky_model/websky.py#L85), the 2nd and 3rd header items also have relevant values, maybe you care about these too?  I've synthesized the following from that code:

```py
RTHMAXin    = headers[1]
redshiftbox = headers[2]
```

Reading more than one record at a time requires re-shaping the data.  To read 3 records:

```py
f = open('halos_10x10.pksc')

np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=3)  # reading, but ignoring header items

three_records = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=3*Nitems_per_record)
print(f'Initial:\n{three_records}')

reshaped_records = np.reshape(three_records, (3, Nitems_per_record))
print(f'Re-shaped:\n{reshaped}')
```

```
Initial:
[ 1170060708 -1011158654 -1006515961 -1022926100  1121164875  1110446585
  1086444250  1170064687 -1011110709 -1006510502  1170083367 -1013908122
 -1006498824 -1014626384 -1020456945 -1033004197  1084104229  1170090354
 -1013985376 -1006510502  1169622353 -1009409432 -1006678295 -1045415727
 -1017794908 -1051267742  1084874393  1169623221 -1009509109 -1006675510]
Re-shaped:
[[ 1170060708 -1011158654 -1006515961 -1022926100  1121164875  1110446585  1086444250  1170064687 -1011110709 -1006510502]
 [ 1170083367 -1013908122 -1006498824 -1014626384 -1020456945 -1033004197  1084104229  1170090354 -1013985376 -1006510502]
 [ 1169622353 -1009409432 -1006678295 -1045415727 -1017794908 -1051267742  1084874393  1169623221 -1009509109 -1006675510]]
```

##### So, what about skipping?

###### Just trim the reshaped data

The easiest thing to do would be read all the data and then trim from the front and back what you don't want:

```py
m = 1
k = 1 * -1
trimmed_records = reshaped_records[m:k]
print(f'Trimmed:\n{trimmed_records}')
```

```
Trimmed:
[[ 1170083367 -1013908122 -1006498824 -1014626384 -1020456945 -1033004197  1084104229  1170090354 -1013985376 -1006510502]]
```

I'm not sure why you want to skip, but that's the easiest to understand and implement.

If you're conern is memory, read on.

###### Discard M records, read less `K+M` records

The next option, as I see it, is to:

1. take the record count (`A` records) from the first header
2. read and *ignore* `M` records
3. figure out how many *remaining* records you have to read, given that you've already read `M` records and want to stop at record `K`: `R = A - M - K`

You'll only save a little memory by ignoring `M` records; the data is still read and interpreted.  You'll definitely save on memory by not reading records `K` to the end:

```py
f = open('halos_10x10.pksc')
headers = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=3)

Arecords = headers[0]
Mrecords = 1_000_000
Krecords = 1_000_000

Nitems = Mrecords * Nitems_per_record
np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems)

Rrecords = Arecords - Mrecords - Krecords  # Remaining records to read
Nitems = Rrecords * Nitems_per_record
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems)
data = np.reshape(data, (Rrecords, Nitems_per_record))

print(f'From {Arecords} to {Rrecords} records:\n{data.shape}')
```

```
From 2079516 to 79516 records:
(79516, 10)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I think no one on SO has put so much effort into answering a question of mine. Preliminary I will accept your answer, but I will have the time to test it only on Sun/Monday. A few things - 1) yes, I need the skipping for memory issues! I actually need to work with the largest file, `halos.pksc`, 33 GB, and it crashes my colab notebook. So I decided to work with one chunk of the file at a time. Let's see if your solution will work smoothly :) 2) Where did you get the info on `.pksc`, I couldn't find it myself?!

Comment: You're welcome, I like the effort... it's fun to figure out. The nature of the PKSC file, I just put together for myself comparing **readhalos.py** and that **websky.py** file. I had a much longer post that was more about my learning process, than a solution. You can check the original version for how I pieced this all together.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to chunk the big files into smaller files, so that you can operate on them independently:

```py
import numpy as np

Nrecords_per_chunk = 100_000
Nitems_per_record = 10

f_in = open('halos_10x10.pksc', 'rb')
headers = np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=3)

Nitems = Nrecords_per_chunk * Nitems_per_record

fnumber = 1
while True:
    items = np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems)

    # Because at the end of the file, we're very likely to get less back than we asked for
    Nrecords_read = int(items.shape[0] / Nitems_per_record)

    # At End Of File: Weird luck, chunk_size was a perfect multiple of number of records
    if Nrecords_read == 0:
        break

    records = np.reshape(items, (Nrecords_read, Nitems_per_record))

    with open(f'halos_{fnumber}.pksc', 'wb') as f_out:
        # Keep same format by having 3 "header" items, each item's value is the record count
        new_headers = np.array([Nrecords_read]*3, dtype=np.int32)
        new_headers.tofile(f_out)
        records.tofile(f_out)

    # At End Of File
    if Nrecords_read < Nrecords_per_chunk:
        break

    fnumber += 1

f_in.close()


# Test that first 100_000 records from the main file match the records from the first chunked file

f_in = open('halos_10x10.pksc')
np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=3)
Nitems = Nrecords_per_chunk * Nitems_per_record
items = np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems)
records_orig = np.reshape(items, (Nrecords_per_chunk, Nitems_per_record))
f_in.close()

f_in = open('halos_1.pksc')
np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=3)
Nitems = Nrecords_per_chunk * Nitems_per_record
items = np.fromfile(f_in, dtype=np.int32, count=Nitems)
records_chunked = np.reshape(items, (Nrecords_per_chunk, Nitems_per_record))
f_in.close()

assert np.array_equal(records_orig, records_chunked)
```